# Installing Mean.io v0.5.5

Tags: mean.io

I messed around with Meanjs.org for a bit and decided to try Mean.io

It seems Mean.io is up to v1.0 when you install via mean-cli. I know because that's what I did. I want to install v0.5.5 and I'm not too familiar with their custom cli tool so...

So I tried going to the 0.5.5 branch on github and cloning that, same thing, v1.0 got installed.

Is there a way to to install Meanio v.5.5?

Comment: I don't see a 0.5.5 branch in https://github.com/meanjs/mean/branches

Comment: @VonC that is for meanjs.org, I'm looking at Mean.io, https://github.com/linnovate/mean/tree/0.5.5